# writing from a SQL view to a Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Hello I've got this SQL View (Namely **Login_Monitor**) that I've created using a number of table joins

What I'm wanting to do now is to use a few columns in this View to write to a seperate table that I've created.

But Im gettiing **Null** values written to table instead of actual data.

This is how I created my destination table

```
create table MS_Login_Monitor
(date date,
time time,
USERID char(15),
COMPANY_NAME char(65),
LOGIN_DATE_TIME datetime,
TIME_SINCE_LAST_ACTION int,
)
```

This is the query I used to write view data to destination table

```
declare @date date
declare @time time
declare @USERID char(20)
declare @COMPANY_NAME char(65)
declare @LOGIN_DATE_TIME datetime
declare @TIME_SINCE_LAST_ACTION nchar(7)


set @date = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
set @time = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

select  * from Login_Monitor

INSERT INTO DYNAMICS..MS_Login_Monitor (date, time,USERID, COMPANY_NAME, LOGIN_DATE_TIME, TIME_SINCE_LAST_ACTION)
 VALUES (@date, @time,@USERID,@COMPANY_NAME, @LOGIN_DATE_TIME, @TIME_SINCE_LAST_ACTION)
```

could someone explain please why I get NULL values written to table please or if there are errors in my SQL query.

Thanks

Comment: Move the `select` after the `insert into (<columnlist>)` line. Instead of using `values` use `select @date, @time, COMPANY_NAME, LOGIN_DATE_TIME, ... from Login_Monitor` Also Instead of using variables you can just select `current_timestamp` in the query and eliminate the need for variables entirely. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Comment: check if your view has nulls

Comment: As for an explanation: You declared a bunch of variables but never gave them values (except for the date and time ones.) You then select rows from the view which are going to your screen/output rather than the table you intended. The insert adds a single row with the values of the variables  which are still null for lack of being initialized/assigned.

Comment: yes does it !!!!! @shawnt00 you're a Star!

Comment: @TheGameiswar, it doesn't matter what their view has. The way this procedure is written the view has no relationship to the insert statement.

Comment: You could always use an ssis data flow task to accomplish this too.

Comment: `@COMPANY_NAME char(65)` - data modelers everywhere are weeping openly because `CHAR(65)` is a terrible choice in SQL Server - unless all company names are exactly 65 characters - because it will take up 65 bytes even if the company name is only 3 characters long.

Comment: Ok folks, please keep your comments on-topic to the post, please stop bickering. I'm cleaning up the comments here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this;

```
INSERT INTO DYNAMICS..MS_Login_Monitor (date, time,USERID, COMPANY_NAME, LOGIN_DATE_TIME, TIME_SINCE_LAST_ACTION)
select  @date, @time, X, Y.....(use actual column names of view) from Login_Monitor
```

You dont need other parameters.